# finding minimum index of a list

Tags: python, list, indexing, min

Hi guys I need help creating a function that will find the minimum index of a list that includes both a list of strings and a list of integers. Right now I can get the function to find either the minimum index of a list of integers or strings but not both at the same time.

```
def find_index_of_min(L):
    """
    Parameter: a list L
    Returns: the index of the minimum element of the list
        (returns None if the list is empty)
    """


    if L == []:
        return None
    elif L == str:
        min = 'Z'
        for i in range(len(L)):
            if L[i] < min:
                min = L[i]
                min_index = i
        return min_index
    elif L == int:
        min = float('inf')
        for i in range(len(L)):
            if L[i] < min:
                min = L[i]
                min_index = i
        return min_index

import sys
import math

def main():
    """ Read and print a file's contents. """

    # filename = str(input('Name of input file: '))
    # string = readfile(filename)
    # print()
    # print('The original list of cities is:')
    # for i in range(len(string)):
    # print(i, ':', string[i], sep="")

    print(find_index_of_min([]))
    print(find_index_of_min([3, 2, 1, 0]))
    print(find_index_of_min(['A', 'Z', 'Y', 'B']))
    print(find_index_of_min(['B', 'A', 'Z', 'Y']))

main()
```

Comment: Too much work. `min()` exists.

Comment: `return L.index(min(L)) if L else None`

Answer (score 1):

You need to replace `L == int` and `L == str` (which will be always valuated to False) with the folowing:

```
all(isinstance(item, str) for item in L)  # L == str
all(isinstance(item, int) for item in L)  # L == int
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

Have a function that checks if the elements inside is a number or a string.

```
def isNumber(s): # Helper function to check if it is a Number or a string
    try:
        float(s)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

def find_index_of_min(L):
    """
    Parameter: a list L
    Returns: the index of the minimum element of the list
        (returns None if the list is empty)
    """

    if L == []:
        return None
    elif isNumber(L[0]):
        min = float('inf')
        for i in range(len(L)):
            if L[i] < min:
                min = L[i]
                min_index = i
        return min_index
    else:
        min = 'Z'
        for i in range(len(L)):
            if L[i] < min:
                min = L[i]
                min_index = i
        return min_index


import sys
import math

def main():
    """ Read and print a file's contents. """

    # filename = str(input('Name of input file: '))
    # string = readfile(filename)
    # print()
    # print('The original list of cities is:')
    # for i in range(len(string)):
    # print(i, ':', string[i], sep="")

    print(find_index_of_min([]))
    print(find_index_of_min([3, 2, 1, 0]))
    print(find_index_of_min(['A', 'Z', 'Y', 'B']))
    print(find_index_of_min(['B', 'A', 'Z', 'Y']))

main()
```